# Join between 2 tables where date_field is between dates

Tags: sql, datetime

I am struggling with how to achieve my desired outcome using SQL.

I have 2 tables that I am trying to join.

1. `Cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl` is a table with all transactions.
2. `cnsmr_accnt_tag` is a table with the tags assigned to accounts.

I am trying to determine which area tag was assigned to an account at the time of a payment.

The way that the `cnsmr_accnt_tag` table works is that when a tag is assigned to an account, the field `cnsmr_accnt_tag_assgn_dt (datetime)` gets updated as well as the field `upsrt_dttm (datetime)` and the field `cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg` is set to **N**.  At this point the `cnsmr_accnt_tag_assgn_dt`  and `upsrt_dttm` fields have the same `datetime`.

When the tag is unassigned, the `cnsmr_accnt_sft_delete_flg` field is set to **Y** and the `upsrt_dttm` is updated to that `datetime` such that the difference between the 2 fields indicates how long the account spent with that tag assigned.

I want to be able to determine which `tag_id` with `tag_typ_id = 60` (the area tag type) was assigned to that account when the payment happened.

The problem is that an account can move into one area, then out again and back in to the same area many times.  It could today be in very different area to where it was when the payment was made or it could be in the same area.  Essentially what I need to do is determine which area tag was assigned most recently (in the past) to the payment.  Any suggestions?

TABLES:
Cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>cnsmr_accnt_id</th>
    <th>cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_amnt</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>562590</td>
     <td>-565.090</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>562590</td>   
      <td>-565.090</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>562607</td>   
      <td>-27208.180</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>562618</td>   
      <td>200.000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words for SQL questions.  Show us sample data for the two tables, along with your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when you say 'picture' the OP might take it literally :)

Comment: please post your sample data as text

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will put something together. Having some issues with posting (getting error messages). Stand by...

Comment: It's difficult to understand without knowing which fields are in which tables, and without some data samples (don't post a picture, post a textual table using code formatting). I _think_ all you need to do is join with `Cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl.transaction_date BETWEEN cnsmr_accnt_tag_assgn_dt  AND upsrt_dttm` to find the one you want. IN your case you would also need to use `EXISTS` to stop double counting.